# why ESLint report line numbers not match with project files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

i have used `eslint-loader` with recommended setup.
this is my setup in webpack:
[image]

and this is my `.eslintrc` file:
[image]
the report showing good in browser console. but the line numbers error from the report not matched with project files.

please help

Comment: Can you include a short code sample and error messages with line numbers that don't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case, the problem is webpack load `eslint-loader` at first than `babel`. i just rewrite position loader babel first and then eslint-loader in webpack config and everything work good :)